# Not able to use the library in Android intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I wanted a file explorer in my application hence while googling I found "[Android File Dialog](http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/)" on code.google.com. The output from the source is a android library which I have included in my Android Project as "Required Project on the Build Path" in project properties dialog. But when I run my application it is giving me exception-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lamerman.FileDialog
```

The line where the error occurs is-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FileDialog.class);
```

This line is in the Activity onCreate method.

I have even added following entry in the **AndroidManifest.xml**-

```
<activity android:name="com.lamerman.FileDialog" />
```

I am not getting any compilation error in Eclipse.

Am I missing some thing while running the application using a Library?

Comment: Did you include the FileDialog.java files in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following the steps mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) click `Setting Up a Project to Use a Library`. Here they have mentioned how you can add a jar file into your library.

If you want to add a library project into your project then follow the steps mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) click `Referencing a library project`